# Unable to click on <label> to select a radio option in form

Tags: radio-button

Working on [this form - form A](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxdLOe?editors=1000) trying to replicate the same behaviour as you can see in [this one - form B](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoxqKG?editors=1000). In the form B, if you click in the `<label>` of each option, it [just works](https://v.usetapes.com/YEKPMg38j2), while in form B, you have to click each one of the `<input>` elements if you want to make a different choice. Why?

Both samples have not CSS included,  no CSS libraries loaded, it's just HTML

**Form A**

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" class="edit_order" id="edit_order_260" method="post">
  <div style="display:none">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="N+XdGRhPcpB+999PYEU5Bs5bvdBYkLd4Ko+cNdhoppA=">
  </div>

  <h3 class="panel-title">
                  <label for="order_Best price"><input checked="checked" id="order_delivery_option_best_price" name="order[delivery_option]" onclick="enable_submit();" type="radio" value="best_price">
                  Best price</label>
                </h3>

  <h3 class="panel-title">
                  <label for="order_Best delivery date"><input id="order_delivery_option_best_delivery_date" name="order[delivery_option]" onclick="enable_submit();" type="radio" value="best_delivery_date">
                  Best delivery date</label>
                </h3>

</form>
```

**Form B**

```
  <form role="form">
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 2</label>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `for` attribute from the labels. For example:

```
<label><input checked="checked" id="order_delivery_option_best_price" name="order[delivery_option]" onclick="enable_submit();" type="radio" value="best_price">Best price</label>
```

Or make `for` value match the value of the `id` attribute of corresponding `input` tag. Like this:

```
<label for="order_delivery_option_best_price"><input checked="checked" id="order_delivery_option_best_price" name="order[delivery_option]" onclick="enable_submit();" type="radio" value="best_price">Best price</label>
```

In this case you don't have to nest the input inside the label and it will still work:)